# Fail to connect to EC2 instance from the root user's shell - Permission denied (publickey) - Windows 10

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, private-key

I can connect to EC2 instance from my computer with SSH as a user tomas  :

```
tomas@machine:~$ ssh ubuntu@ec2-3-91-55-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1045-aws x86_64)
```

But when I'm a root user I get an error :

```
root@machine:~$ ssh ubuntu@ec2-3-91-55-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ubuntu@ec2-3-91-55-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am using MobaXterm as my terminal and I have added a private key to be loaded at start up.

How can I fix this so I could connect to EC2 both from "tomas" shell and "root" shell ?

I have tried :

```
chmod 400 mykey.pem
```

Comment: is this a silly question ?

Comment: This might be because  IAM user "tomas" has an Access Key, however
root user doesn't have an Access Key created.